# Magnetic filed at a Helmholtz coil center

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I understand that a magnetic field, B,  at a center of a circular coil is:

\begin{equation}
    B = \frac{N \mu_0 i}{2a}
\end{equation}

where $N$ is the number of turns of the coil, $\mu_0$ is the magnetic permeability of the air, $i$ is the electric current in the coil and $a$ is the radius of the coil.

But, how to demonstrate that, for a Helmholtz coil, the magnetic field is:

\begin{equation}
    B = \frac{N \mu_0 i}{(5/4)^{3/2}a}
\end{equation}

Comment: Have you looked at [Wikipedia's derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_coil#Derivation)?

Comment: Yes, now I understood. Thank you